Relationship Between Borel and Lebesgue Measurable Sets
I'm currently going through Real Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi. On page 23 of the book, Stein claims that the set of all Lebesgue measurable sets can be given by adjoining all subsets of Borel sets of measure zero, with the $\sigma$ algebra of Borel sets.
He claims that this follows Corollary 3.5, which then states that a subset E of $R^d$ is measurable if and only if E differs from a $G_{\delta}$ by a set of measure zero. Note that $G_{\delta}$ is a set formed from countable intersections of open sets.
I don't understand why the result in the first paragraph follows from Corollary 3.5. Say we have a subset E of $R^d$. Then we know for some $G_{\delta}$, $E \subset G_{\delta}$ and $G_{\delta} - E$ has measure 0. But how does that imply E can be formed by the union between some Borel Set and some subset of a Borel set with measure zero? $G_{\delta}$ is a Borel set, and $G_{\delta} - E$ has measure 0, but $G_{\delta} \cup (G_{\delta} - E)$ isn't $E$.
Have I misunderstood Stein somewhere? Thanks in advance.

The way I would interpret it is just that the authors are saying that the completion is the sigma algebra generated by adding the null sets to the Borel sigma algebra. In this case, it suffices to note that $E$ is the difference of a $G_\delta$ set and a null set.
Or, if you like, you can use the other part of 3.5, where there's an $F_\sigma \subseteq E$ such that $m(E-F_\sigma)=0.$ Then $E= F_\sigma \cup E-F_\sigma$ is the union of a Borel set and a null set. So the way you seem to be interpreting it (the sets that can be expressed as a union of a Borel set and a null set) is true too.
I'm not sure what to make of the phrasing "all subsets of Borel sets of measure zero", as opposed to just saying "all null sets"… it seems more awkward than necessary. If they mean "all null subsets of Borel sets", well, every set is a subset of a Borel set (e.g. $\mathbb R^n)$ so that's just saying every null set. If they mean "all subsets of null Borel sets", then by the same theorem, every null set is a subset of a null $G_\delta$ set, so again, it just means the same thing as all null sets.

Regarding “$E$ differs from a $G_{\delta}$ by a set of measure zero”, I would interpret this in the same way as, for a real number $x$, saying that “$x$ differs from an integer by a number less than $\frac{1}{100}$”. In this analogy, “integer” is playing the role of niceness and “less than $\frac{1}{100}$” is playing the role of smallness. Consider the following two cases involved in this version for numbers:
Case (i) For some integer $n$ we have $n-x < \frac{1}{100}.$ That is, by increasing $x$ a small amount we can obtain an integer.
Case (ii) For some integer $n$ we have $x-n < \frac{1}{100}.$ That is, by decreasing $x$ a small amount we can obtain an integer.
Case (i) in your situation is that by increasing $E$ a small amount we can obtain a $G_{\delta}$ set. Thus, letting $G$ be any such $G_{\delta}$ set that works for $E$ (clearly the choice of $G_{\delta}$ set that works for $E$ is not unique; for example, once you have such a $G_{\delta}$ set, adding a single point to it gives another such $G_{\delta}$ set), the inclusion $E \subseteq G$ and the equality $E \cup (G-E) = G$ shows that adding the measure zero set $G-E$ to the measurable set $E$ gives a $G_{\delta}$ set.
Case (ii) in your situation is that by decreasing $E$ a small amount we can obtain an $F_{\sigma}$ set. Thus, letting $F$ be any such $F_{\sigma}$ set that works for $E$ (clearly the choice of $F_{\sigma}$ set that works for $E$ is not unique; for example, once you have such an $F_{\sigma}$ set, removing a single point from it gives another such $F_{\sigma}$ set), the inclusion $F \subseteq E$ and the equality $E - (E-F) = F$ shows that subtracting the measure zero set $E-F$ from the measurable set $E$ gives an $F_{\sigma}$ set.
Regarding your confusion with

But how does that imply E can be formed by the union between some Borel Set and some subset of a Borel set with measure zero? $G_{\delta}$ is a Borel set, and $G_{\delta} - E$ has measure 0, but $G_{\delta} \cup (G_{\delta} - E)$ isn't $E$.

I think what is happening is that you are conflating (a) set containment between $E$ and $G$ (these are subsets of $R^d)$ with (b) set containment between the collection of measurable sets and the collection of $G_{\delta}$ sets (these are collections of subsets of $R^d).$ Although $E$ is a subset of $G,$ the collection of measurable sets is a superset of the collection of $G_{\delta}$ sets. Also, the collection of measurable sets is a superset of the collection of $F_{\sigma}$ sets.
Worth mentioning is that in many ways the collection of measurable sets is much vaster than either of these two other collections (even their union). For example, each of the collections of $G_{\delta}$ sets and of $F_{\sigma}$ sets has cardinality $\mathfrak c,$ but the collection of measure zero sets has cardinality $2^{\mathfrak c}.$ Although individually the measure zero sets are small and negligible, there are MANY MANY more of them than of $G_{\delta}$ sets or of $F_{\sigma}$ sets. The $G_{\delta}$ sets and the $F_{\sigma}$ sets are like elephants and lions, while the measure zero sets are like insects (or perhaps bacteria).
